# Attach View of Model to existing DIV in Backbone

Tags: javascript, dom, backbone.js, backbone-views

need help, can't understand how to attach each View of the model to each already existing DIV in DOM ( have and div.container with div.widget array ).

```
// Model
V.Models.Shortcode = Backbone.Model.extend({});

// Shortcodes Collection Init
V.Collections.Shortcodes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: V.Models.Shortcode,
});
```

**When Iframe load, push storage from server to collection:**

```
$('#preview').on('load', function() {

var ShortcodesCollection = new V.Collections.Shortcodes( Vision.ShortcodeStorage );

var Preview = new V.Views.Preview({
    collection: ShortcodesCollection,
    el: $('.container')
});

Preview.render();

});
```

**Render Preview with collection:**

```
// Collection View in iframe
V.Views.Preview = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize: function() {
  this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this);
},

render: function() {
  this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
  return this;
},

addOne: function(ad) {
  var shortcodeView = new V.Views.Shortcode({ model: ad });
  shortcodeView.render();
}
});
```

**View for each Model:**

```
// Shortcode View
V.Views.Shortcode = Backbone.View.extend({
 events: {
    'click .widget' : 'SomeActionOnView'
 },

 render: function(){
    //console.log(this.el);
    //console.log(this.model.toJSON());
 },

 SomeActionOnView: function(){
    console.log(this);
 }
 });
```

Question is, how to attach V.Views.Shortcode to each div with "widget" class to bind events. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to append your all views under div with class "widget"?

Comment: @Nitesh want to append each View to each .widget

Comment: Do you need to create a new div.widget for every view?

Comment: @Nitesh no, all div.widget already exists in my DOM on document.ready, what's a problem why i can't understand how to append View to already exists div.widget's

Comment: Can you try this?
$("div.widget").append(this.$el);

Comment: @Nitesh where do this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this?

```
V.Views.Shortcode = Backbone.View.extend({
     events: {
        'click .widget' : 'SomeActionOnView'
     },

     render: function(){
      //code here to write stuff of this.$el
       $("div.widget").append(this.$el);
     },

     SomeActionOnView: function(){
        console.log(this);
     }
     });
```

Comment: wait a moment please, will try

Comment: It will just append current view inside div.widget.
If you have div.widget div on your UI, you will see your view appearing there.

This is a backbone view. If you want to return current view, you can write return this at the end.

Comment: it's just return div's and div context, not div.widget ( with "return this;"  similar situation ) : http://take.ms/XEBE4

Comment: Why do you need to return div.widget?
In this render function, you have already appended your view inside div.widget.

Now anywhere you access $("div.widget"), your content will be already available.

Also, you should only return this from render.Not anything else.

Comment: http://take.ms/EO54F in this code your answer doesn't work, "click" event doesn't work in my 'V.Views.Shortcode', this returns me nothing, i need return div.widget to add Events to change my DOM

Comment: Backbone view events only work on the view and its descendants. You are appending `V.View.ShortCode` to `.vswidget`. But the code `'click .vswidget' : 'action'` means,  "When user clicks on `V.View.ShortCode` element, check its descendants for element with class `vswidget` and if found, call callback function. This cannot happen because `.vswidget` is an ancestor of shortcode, not a descendant.